# VS C++ coderunner not printing to output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Hi I am a relatively new c++ programmer and I am using Visual Studio to code C++ but whenever I try to run the code, it does not show in the output (where the execution time is shown) but prints to the terminal in VS. I have already disabled output to terminal in setting so I am unsure of what else I can do.
Any help would be appreciated.

I also uninstalled and reintalled both coderunner and visual studio. I also reinstalled clang and g++. Currently I am on a Macook pro with Sonoma

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.